# How to perform row wise math operations in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How to perform row wise math operations in SQL Server?

eg: I want to find the average of marks for a particular student like as shown in the table below

```
Student     Mark1   Mark2   Mark3   Avg
-----------------------------------------------
Ram         78       81      56     71.67
Jos         92       67      54     71.00
Saj         98       91      89     92.67
```

Comment: define your row wise math, include data sample and desire output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Student, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3, 1.0 * (Mark1 + Mark2 + Mark3)/3 as Avg
FROM YourTable
```

Add the `1.0 *` to convert the SUM result to float before the division

Answer (score 0):

this query also helps you to get exact results

**SELECT 
 Student, 
 Mark1,
 Mark2,
 Mark3,
(Mark1 + Mark2 + Mark3)/3*100 as Avg
FROM YourTable**

Comment: SELECT Student, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3, ((Mark1 + Mark2 + Mark3)/3)*100 as Avg FROM YourTable

Comment: Multiplying with 100 is not needed

Answer (score 0):

This would work
**select student,mrk1,mrk2,mrk3,1.0*((mrk1+mrk2+mrk3)/3)  Avg from student**
check you calculation in avg column.